# How to Call Another Route in Silex Framework

Tags: php, silex

I'm using Silex framework and need to call

```
$app->get('/users/')
```

inside

```
$app->get('/user/create/{username}'
```

after creating the new user. How can I do it?

Below is my sample codes:

```
$app->get('/users/', function(Application $app) {
  ....
});

$app->get('/user/create/{username}', function(Application $app, $username) {
  ....
  **redirect to  $app->get('/users/')**
});
```

Comment: as suggession, did you try middleware ?

Answer (score 0):

got the answer!

```
return $app->redirect('/users/');
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11369930)

Comment: @sebastianbrosch: That _is_ the answer.